# Load data from table using PHP & AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to retrieve data from table using PHP and AJAX, at the moment I'm able to display the result of my query in json format, what I want to do is select an specific data from that array, for example I get this array:

> {data: [{IdProduct: "1", Name: "Name here..........",…}]}

For example I want to select only Name, I tried doing this:

```
function LoadProductos() {

$.ajax({
    url: '../../class/loadProd.php',
    method: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
      var aRC = JSON.parse(data);

      for (var i = 0; i < aRC.length; i++) {
        console.log(aRC[i].Name);
      }
    }

  });
}
```

But this doesn't shows anything, how can I do this? This is my PHP code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {

    $table.='{
        "IdProduct":"'.$row['IdProduct'].'",
        "Name":"'.$row['Name'].'",
        "Description":"'.$row['Description'].'",
        "ImagePath":"'.$row['ImagePath'].'"
    },';

    $table = substr($table, 0, strlen($table) -1);

    echo '{"data":['.$table.']}';
}
```

Comment: You're trying to parse JSON data on return, but you're not creating vaild JSON data in the PHP. Use `json_encode()`, never try to code JSON on your own.

Comment: Don't build your own json-string. Just create a PHP array and encode it with [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) instead.

Comment: The last two lines ($table = ... and echo ...) should be after the loop.

Comment: _Suggestion:_ Instead of `substr($table, 0, strlen($table) -1)`, trim the string: `trim($table, ',')`. (In other situations, that is. Here you should still use json:encode(), as mentioned).

Comment: Ok, now I get it! I'm new with PHP, one thing... how can I use json_encode() with my current code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are couple of things you need to change in your code, such as:

- That's not how you should create a json string. Create an empty array before the `while()` loop and append the row details to this array in each iteration of the loop. And after coming out of the loop, simply apply [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function to the resultant array to get the final json string.

  ```
  $table = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {
      $table[]= array(
          'IdProduct' => $row['IdProduct'],
          'Name' => $row['Name'],
          'Description' => $row['Description'],
          'ImagePath' => $row['ImagePath']
      );
  }
  echo json_encode($table);
  ```
- Since you're expecting a json string from server, add this setting `dataType:'json'` to your AJAX request. `dataType` is the type of data you're expecting back from the server. And in the `success()` callback function, simply loop through the json result to get the relevant data.

  ```
  function LoadProductos() {
      $.ajax({
          url: '../../class/loadProd.php',
          method: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {
              for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                  alert(data[i].Name);
              }
          }
      });
  }
  ```

Comment: I made the changes but now I don't get any type of information (from echo json_encode) and there is no error messages too

Comment: @User1899289003 Couple of things to debug here, 1) Did you call this `LoadProductos()` function? 2) Do `alert(data);` in the `success` callback function and see what you're getting there.

Comment: Yes! I'm calling my function and also I alert(data), I also open browser console to see what's happen and the function is executed fine, but in Preview/Response window there is nothing, I change echo json_encode($table) to echo "hello" and works properly.

Comment: @User1899289003 Paste your jQuery/AJAX and PHP code in [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/) and give me it's link here.

Comment: @User1899289003 You didn't include `dataType: 'json'` setting in your AJAX request. There are actually two ways you can achieve your desired result, both ways are listed here(*LoadProductos* function), [https://pastebin.com/WxuTffZh](https://pastebin.com/WxuTffZh)

Comment: I change my code but I'm still getting an empty array!

Comment: Ready! The code it's ok, the problem was that I have special characters and this broke the json_encode(), there is a way to avoid this?

Comment: @User1899289003 Not sure what those special characters are but your input has to be encoded as `UTF-8` or `ISO-8859-1`. There are couple of SO threads on this issue, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20694317/5517143 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/7284535/5517143

Comment: Ready! I just made this: utf8_encode($row['Name']), btw... special characters are this á, ó, something like that. Thanks for your help buddy!

Comment: @User1899289003 You're welcome! Glad I could help. :-)

Answer (score 2):

First off, your shouldn't echo the json data *in* the loop. It should be *outside* the loop. 
You shouldn't build your own json data either.

Let's build an array that looks like the json response you want. Then we'll use the function `json_encode()` to encode it as a proper json-string:

```
// Define the response array
$response = [
    'data' => []
];

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {

    // Push a new array to 'data' array
    $response['data'][] = [
        'IdProduct'   => $row['IdProduct'],
        'Name'        =>.$row['Name'],
        'Description' => $row['Description'],
        'ImagePath'   => $row['ImagePath']
    ];
}

// Now, let's encode the data:
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: I also tried this but I get the error from above answer.

Comment: @User1899289003 Check your servers error log and see if it says something. What PHP version/OS are you running this on?

Comment: There is no error messages or logs, I use PHP 5.6.30

Answer (score 0):

In you PHP file make changes according to this:-

```
$outp = array();
$outp = $res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

For make sure that json_encode don't return null

```
function utf8ize($d) {
 if (is_array($d)) {
    foreach ($d as $k => $v) {
        $d[$k] = utf8ize($v);
    }
} else if (is_string ($d)) {
    return utf8_encode($d);
}
return $d;
}
echo json_encode(utf8ize($outp));
```

You JavaScript is okay You just need to change code in PHP.